# Passing objects to next sibling components

Tags: aurelia

My structure in AureliaJS of components is:

```
<parent>
  <child1> 
  <child2> 
</parent>
```

I have an object in `child1` which I get with ajax requests:

```
export class Child1 {   
  fechedObject = {}: 
}
```

I need this property with two-way binding and observable in the second component

```
export class Child2 {   
  // I need this fechedObject here 
}
```

What is the best approach to get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the best approach here is using two-way binding on both child models, to bind the model via two-way binding in the parent.

In your `parent.html`, you would need this:

```
<child1 fetched-object.two-way="fetchedObject"></child1>

<child2 fetched-object.two-way="fetchedObject"></child2>
```

And in both child view-models, you'd declare the variable as a `bindable`:

```
bindable()
public fechedObject;
```

This way any edits that happen in either children, will get passed on to the other child. If you want to prevent edits in `child2` from affecting the object in `child1`, you can simply bind one-way using `fechedObject.one-way` or `fechedObject.bind` on your `child2`.

Comment: Just a side note: with this, if the object being fetched comes before bind, `fetchedObject` will be `undefined`.

Comment: Jesse, That`s a good approach and works quite well ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get a hold of `<child1/>` view model reference and bind it to `<child2/>`:

```
<child1 view-model.ref='child1'></child1>

<child2 data.bind='child1.fetchedObject'></child2>
```

So `child.data` just needs to be bindable:

```
export class Child2 {

  @bindable
  data
}
```

Comment: whould it be cleaner to decalre it as `bindable` in `child1` as well? (with 2 way)? instead of getting access of all the `view-model`? also - by looking in `child1` we whould now that it has an `exported` property.

Comment: Yes, both children can be bound to same property of parent so they can interconnect. I was using the answer as an opportunity to introduce ref feature, than can be useful in the feature when it involves more than just a simple property