# How can I pass data between two views in Aurelia?

Tags: javascript, html, aurelia

I have two views, `logo` and `folder`, that folder recall in logo, I am going to check if folder is empty send something into logo view.

**logo.html**

```html
<template>
  <require from="company-assets/folders"></require>

  <folders resourcetype="logo" loadresources.bind="bindedLoadResources" 
     isloading.bind="bindedIsLoading" rootitems.bind="rootResources" if.bind="!searchQuery">
  </folders>

  <ul class="row logos list" if.bind="resourcesList.items.length">
    <logo repeat.for="logo of resourcesList.items" item.bind="logo"></logo>
  </ul>

  <div if.bind="resourcesList.items.length==0 && 
    !resourcesList.isLoading || folders.resourcetype"  >
    <assest-emptyscreens></assest-emptyscreens>
  </div>


</template>
```

**folder.html**

```html
<template>

  <ul class="row folders list mb-30 mt-10" if.bind="!isLoading && hasFolders">
    <folder if.bind="resourcetype" repeat.for="folder of foldersList.items" 
      item.bind="folder" loadfoldercontent.bind="bindedGoToFolder" 
      isloading.bind="bindedIsLoading" deletedfolder.bind="bindedDeletedFolder">
    </folder>
  </ul>

  <div if.bind="!hasFolders && isRoot && !isLoading" >
    Empty
  </div>
</template>
```

I gonna get "empty" from folder to check in logo

Comment: There are two methods to pass data between components. First is to use Observer/Listener pattern. This is nicely supported by Aurelia's EventAggregator, see e.g. tutorial at https://aurelia.io/docs/tutorials/creating-a-contact-manager#adding-pubsub-messaging Other method is to share property of parent viewmodel it's somewhere already answered here cannot find a link.

Comment: @TomasKulhanek [Passing objects to sibling components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173579/passing-objects-to-next-sibling-components) - this one?

Comment: Also, I have no idea what you're asking. Could you please tidy up your sentencing and clearly describe your problem? I also feel like there's a lot of unnecessary code in your snippets, try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: tnx, the first link was great .https://aurelia.io/docs/tutorials/creating-a-contact-manager#adding-pubsub-messaging

Comment: @JessedeBruijne yes that's the link to correct answer.

Comment: thnx @TomasKulhanek

Answer (score 0):

There are generally two methods to pass data between components.

1. First is to use Observer/Listener or Publisher/Subscriber pattern. This is nicely supported by Aurelia's EventAggregator, see e.g. tutorial at https://aurelia.io/docs/tutorials/creating-a-contact-manager#adding-pubsub-messaging
2. Shared property of viewmodel. See answer at [Passing objects to next sibling components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173579/passing-objects-to-next-sibling-components)